# Create a surface plot without actually displaying it in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I would like to create a surface plot without actually displaying it. I just want to export the graph to a PNG. Here is the relevant code:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot, cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title, show
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(11, 7), dpi=100)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.view_init(30, 225)
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, p[:], rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
pyplot.pause(.001)
pyplot.savefig("images/blah" + str(counter)+".png")
```

Note that the variables are all fine and there is no bug (it's a lot of math so I cut it for ease of reading) I just can't figure out how to export to a PNG without displaying the figure itself.

Comment: It shouldn't display anything. But just to make sure, what happens if you remove the line `pyplot.pause(.001)`?

Comment: Huh, that worked! That's surprising, can you explain why that is?

Comment: `pause` is only useful when displaying the figure, so it will draw it. Now it seems you are in interactive mode. In interactive mode `draw` will actually display the figure on screen.

Comment: Some IDE like Spider show the images by default. If you execute your code on a terminal, the plot is not displayed if you don't add the line plt.show(). Can you tell us what IDE are you using?